# Convert VARCHAR2 into Number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a column named `duration`. Its data type is `VARCHAR2`.

I want to sum the column `duration`.

```
00:56:30
02:08:40
01:01:00
```

Total=> `04:05:10`

How can I do this using ANSI SQL or Oracle SQL?

Comment: What if total is over `99:59:59`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can separate the hours, mins and seconds using `SUBSTR`, then `SUM` it up and finally use `NUMTODSINTERVAL` function to convert it into `INTERVAL` type.

```
SELECT NUMTODSINTERVAL (SUM (total_secs), 'second')
  FROM (SELECT   SUBSTR (duration, 1, 2) * 3600
               + SUBSTR (duration, 4, 2) * 60
               + SUBSTR (duration, 7, 2) total_secs
          FROM user_tab);
```

Comment: Nice solution. Though I think it would be a bit safer to use regular expression unless the input is always well formatted.

Comment: Тhanks аll of you for helping me :) Function Numtodsinterval for Oracle is really useful.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's better to convert your strings to `INTERVAL` first, and add these values as date values. Something along the lines of:

```
select   to_dsinterval('0 00:56:30') 
       + to_dsinterval('0 02:08:40') 
       + to_dsinterval('0 01:01:00') myinterval from dual;

MYINTERVAL
-------------------
+000000000 04:06:10
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I found that `sum` aggregate function doesn't work with `INTERVAL` data type, so you should either use PL/SQL code to iterate over all records to aggregate `INTERVAL` values, or write your own aggregate function as described [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=291552) on Oracle OTN Discussion Forums or [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5269744394385) (Ask Tom).

Answer (score 4):

### FOR ORACLE

```
select 
numtodsinterval(sum(
  to_char(to_date(duration, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24') * 3600 + 
  to_char(to_date(duration, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'MI') * 60+
  to_char(to_date(duration, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'SS')
  ), 'second'
) as SUMTOTAL
from tbl;
```

Second query

```
select 
numtodsinterval(hr+mn+sc, 'second')
from 
(
select 
sum(to_char(to_date(duration, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH24') * 3600) as hr,
sum(to_char(to_date(duration, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'MI') * 60) as mn,
sum(to_char(to_date(duration, 'HH24:MI:SS'), 'SS'))as sc
from tbl) tmp
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0bab5/26)**

Example returning an object in SQL FIDDLE. try on your machine

### FOR MYSQL

Try this

```
select sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(duration))) from tbl
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f4d2/2)**

```
| SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(DURATION))) |
-------------------------------------------
|          January, 01 1970 04:06:10+0000 |
```

Comment: The OP includes `oracle` tag though ;-)

Comment: The OP changed the tag after I answered the question.......  Have changed the answer.

Comment: The question has [always been tagged Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16812762/revisions)... not that it matters now you've updated your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; please be sure to pay attention to little details like what language/DBMS someone is using in the future.

Answer (score 2):

For fun, I wrote my own aggregate function that can sum intervals (see @Yasir's post).  This could be modified to do the varchar to interval conversions internally, but I'll keep it as simple as possible for now).

First create the object type spec:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SumInterval 
AS OBJECT (

runningSum INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(9),

STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize
  ( actx IN OUT SumInterval
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate
  ( self  IN OUT SumInterval,
    val   IN       DSINTERVAL_UNCONSTRAINED
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate
  ( self             IN   SumInterval,
    returnValue  OUT DSINTERVAL_UNCONSTRAINED,
    flags           IN   NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER,

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge
  (self  IN OUT SumInterval,
   ctx2 IN      SumInterval
  ) RETURN NUMBER

);
```

And the object body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY SumInterval AS

STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize
  ( actx IN OUT SumInterval
  ) RETURN NUMBER IS 
  BEGIN
    IF actx IS NULL THEN
      actx := SumInterval (INTERVAL '0 0:0:0.0' DAY TO SECOND);
    ELSE
      actx.runningSum := INTERVAL '0 0:0:0.0' DAY TO SECOND;
    END IF;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate
  ( self  IN OUT SumInterval,
    val   IN     DSINTERVAL_UNCONSTRAINED
  ) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    self.runningSum := self.runningSum + val;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate
  ( self        IN  SumInterval,
    ReturnValue OUT DSINTERVAL_UNCONSTRAINED,
    flags       IN  NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := self.runningSum;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge
  (self IN OUT SumInterval,
   ctx2 IN     SumInterval
  ) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    self.runningSum := self.runningSum + ctx2.runningSum;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

END;
```

And finally the function that uses this object type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_interval( x DSINTERVAL_UNCONSTRAINED) 
RETURN DSINTERVAL_UNCONSTRAINED  PARALLEL_ENABLE
AGGREGATE USING SumInterval;
```

Now you can use the new "sum_interval" as follows:

```
with x as (
select to_dsinterval('0 00:56:30') as duration from dual
union
select to_dsinterval('0 02:08:40') as duration from dual
union
select to_dsinterval('0 01:01:00') as duration from dual
)
select sum_interval(duration)
from x;
```

Output:

```
SUM_INTERVAL(DURATION)
+00 04:06:10.000000
```

Whats also nice about this is that it can be used similar to a typical aggregate function.  For example, we can use as a group function:

```
with x as (
select 'FL' as state, to_dsinterval('0 00:56:30') as duration from dual
union
select 'FL' as state, to_dsinterval('0 02:08:40') as duration from dual
union
select 'GA' as state, to_dsinterval('0 01:01:00') as duration from dual
)
select state, sum_interval(duration)
from x
group by state;
```

output:

```
STATE   SUM_INTERVAL(DURATION)
FL  +00 03:05:10.000000
GA  +00 01:01:00.000000
```