# Adding Time in HH:MM Format -SQL Query

Tags: sql, time, oracle11g, timestamp

Sir/Mam,

I am using Oracle 11g.I have the following table by the name "Timeduration". It contains time specified in hours and minutes.I want to get the total time in hour and minutes.

```
Timeduration
05:37
06:40
03:45
02:50
07:58
```

I want the total time as 25:30. How can i write the code for this?? Please help me out."

Comment: Use Aggregate Function `SUM()`. Check http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/207655/Adding-Time-in-HH-MM-Format-Useful-SQL-Query

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812762/convert-varchar2-into-number

Answer (score 1):

```
with t as (
  select '05:37' as timeduration from dual union all
  select '06:40' as timeduration from dual union all
  select '03:45' as timeduration from dual union all
  select '02:50' as timeduration from dual union all
  select '07:58' as timeduration from dual
),
d as (
  select 
      --
      --  4  Converting the sum obtained in (3) into
      --     an interval
    numtodsinterval(
      -- 
      --  3  Summing the day fractions obtained in (2)
      sum(
      --
      --  1  Convert the string 'HH:MM' to a real date.
      --
      --     For example 05:37 becomes January 1st 0001 5:37
             to_date('00010101' || t.timeduration, 'yyyymmddhh24:mi') 
      --
      --  2  Subtract January 1st 0001 from that date
      --
      --     The result is a number of a day's length
      --    [1: 24 hours, 0.3: 8 hours etc)
           - date '0001-01-01'),
      --
          'DAY'
    ) interval
  from
    t
)
select
   (
      --  5  How many days are in the interval. Each day
      --     corresponds to 24 hours:
      extract (day  from d.interval) * 24 +
      --
      --  6  The hours «below» 24 hours must be added
      --     seperatly:
      extract (hour from d.interval) 
   ) 
      --
      --  7  Hours are now extracted. Append the delimiter
     || ':' ||
   (
      --
      --  8  Finally: get the minutes from the interval
      extract (minute from d.interval)
   )
   result
from d;
```