# Adding all Time values in a column

Tags: sql, time, addition, toad

I have the following data

```
    Shift_Working_Hours
    --------------------
    03:45
    09:00
    08:45
    07:50
```

I want to add up all the values in the Shift_Working_Hours column and I want the result as 28:40.
Please guide me how can i do it using SQL.
I am using TOAD.

Comment: Is this a `time` or a `string` column?

Comment: Should it really return `28:40` instead of `29:20`?

Comment: Isn't toad a client tool? What type of database system are you connecting to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Time in HH:MM Format -SQL Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012164/adding-time-in-hhmm-format-sql-query)

Comment: Sorry Sir, you are right.

Comment: It should return 29:20 only

Comment: It is a VARCHAR2 column

Answer (score 0):

```
-- If it String Column



  Select convert(varchar,sum(convert(int,parsename(replace(WH,':',''),2)
    +(sum(convert(int,parsename(replace(WH,':',''),1)/60))+':'
    +convert(varchar,(sum(convert(int,parsename(replace(WH,':',''),2)%60))
    from table


    -- If it is a datecolumn
Select convert(varchar,SUM(DATEPART(hh,Wh))+
SUM(DATEPART(mm,WH))/60)+':'+
convert(varchar,SUM(DATEPART(mm,WH))%60)
```