# Calculate sum of spent time

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I have a sql query that calculates spent time for concurrent jobs. Here is the query:

```
SELECT
             user_concurrent_program_name,
             DECODE (phase_code, 'C', 'Completed', phase_code) phase_code,
             DECODE (status_code,
                     'D', 'Cancelled',
                     'E', 'Error',
                     'G', 'Warning',
                     'H', 'On Hold',
                     'T', 'Terminating',
                     'M', 'No Manager',
                     'X', 'Terminated',
                     'C', 'Normal',
                     status_code)
                AS status_code,
          TO_CHAR (
              to_date('2001,091,00:00:00' , 'YYYY,DDD,HH24:MI:SS')
               + (ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE - ACTUAL_START_DATE),
               'HH24:MI:SS')
            AS GECEN_SURE
        FROM apps.fnd_conc_req_summary_v
       WHERE phase_code = 'C' AND status_code = 'C';
```

Here is a couple of rows when i run it:

```
Initial Mass Copy                       Completed   Normal  22:12:35
Gather Schema Statistics                Completed   Normal  06:13:35
Request Set FAH-KPK Fislerini Olustur   Completed   Normal  04:36:36
Request Set FAH-KPK Fislerini Olustur   Completed   Normal  04:15:18
Request Set FAH-KPK Fislerini Olustur   Completed   Normal  04:13:45
Request Set FAH-KPK Fislerini Olustur   Completed   Normal  04:10:51
```

What i want is get the sum of spent time. So my query result will be like:

```
    Initial Mass Copy                           Completed   Normal  22:12:35
    Gather Schema Statistics                Completed   Normal  06:13:35
    Request Set FAH-KPK Fislerini Olustur   Completed   Normal  17:02:36
```

Comment: start by removing the time format in your query - just make a number.  Then use the whole thing as an inline view, and sum up the seconds. THEN format it back to HH24:MI:ss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like in this [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/df494/1/0)

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
   A   CHAR (1),
   b   VARCHAR2 (10)
);

INSERT INTO TEST
     VALUES ('A', '04:00:01');

INSERT INTO TEST
     VALUES ('A', '04:00:01');

INSERT INTO TEST
     VALUES ('A', '13:02:01');

INSERT INTO TEST
     VALUES ('A', '11:00:01');

INSERT INTO TEST
     VALUES ('A', '02:59:59');

COMMIT;

SELECT    TO_CHAR (TRUNC (total / 3600))
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR (TRUNC (ABS (MOD (total, 3600)) / 60), 'fm00')
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR (MOD (total, 60), 'fm00')
  FROM (SELECT SUM (
                    TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (b, 1, 2)) * 60 * 60
                  + TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (b, 4, 2)) * 60
                  + TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (b, 7, 2)))
                  TOTAL
          FROM TEST);
35:02:03
```

**PS:** This can be included in your aggregation part.

So it should be something like this

```
WITH TEST
     AS (SELECT user_concurrent_program_name,
                DECODE (phase_code, 'C', 'Completed', phase_code) phase_code,
                DECODE (status_code,
                        'D', 'Cancelled',
                        'E', 'Error',
                        'G', 'Warning',
                        'H', 'On Hold',
                        'T', 'Terminating',
                        'M', 'No Manager',
                        'X', 'Terminated',
                        'C', 'Normal',
                        status_code)
                   AS status_code,
                TO_CHAR (
                     TO_DATE ('2001,091,00:00:00', 'YYYY,DDD,HH24:MI:SS')
                   + (ACTUAL_COMPLETION_DATE - ACTUAL_START_DATE),
                   'HH24:MI:SS')
                   AS GECEN_SURE
           FROM apps.fnd_conc_req_summary_v
          WHERE phase_code = 'C' AND status_code = 'C')
SELECT user_concurrent_program_name,
       phase_code,
       status_code,
          TO_CHAR (TRUNC (GECEN_SURE/ 3600))
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR (TRUNC (ABS (MOD (GECEN_SURE, 3600)) / 60), 'fm00')
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR (MOD (GECEN_SURE, 60), 'fm00') TOTAL
  FROM (  SELECT user_concurrent_program_name,
                 phase_code,
                 status_code,
                 SUM (
                      TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (GECEN_SURE, 1, 2)) * 60 * 60
                    + TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (GECEN_SURE, 4, 2)) * 60
                    + TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (GECEN_SURE, 7, 2)))
                    GECEN_SURE
            FROM TEST
        GROUP BY user_concurrent_program_name, phase_code, status_code);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it takes too much time to execute the query. Is there anything we can do to improve performance?

Comment: This is much intensive in terms of in built function usage. Better keep this functionality at the end. I mean split it into two queries. You can also look forward to club the queries into one.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you want to sum time intervals.  If you have dates for start and end times, you can cast them to timestamps and then subtract them, giving you intervals.  The tricky part is aggregating intervals, which you'll need a custom aggregate function.

To sum intervals, please see my previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812762/convert-varchar2-into-number/16816494#16816494)

Once you compile that, you can simply do the following:

```
with d as (
    -- 1 day duration
    select 'X' as typ, sysdate - 4 as start_dte, sysdate - 3 as end_dte from dual
    union all
    -- 1.5 days duration
    select 'X' as typ, sysdate - 3 as start_dte, sysdate - 1.5 as end_dte from dual
    union all
    -- 0.5 days duration
    select 'Y' as typ, sysdate - 1.5 as start_dte, sysdate - 1 as end_dte from dual
    union all
    -- 1 day duration
    select 'Z' as typ, sysdate - 1 as start_dte, sysdate as end_dte from dual
)
-- subtract timestamp gives intervals
select typ, sum_interval(cast(end_dte as timestamp) - cast(start_dte as timestamp)) as duration
from d
group by typ;
```

Output:

```
TYP DURATION
X   +02 12:00:00.000000
Y   +00 12:00:00.000000
Z   +01 00:00:00.000000
```