# Sum of INTERVAL DAY in Oracle

Tags: oracle, dateinterval

I have a table `TABLE4`, with the `COLUMN1` have the following values,

```
0 2:2:30.361000000
0 3:15:40.899000000
0 3:7:38.128000000
```

with the data type as `INTERVAL DAY(2) TO SECOND(6)`

I need to add these times.I was trying to add this like,

`select sum(column1) from table4`

And failed. `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`
Can I add the time INTERVAL? Or do I need to split it up to add separately?

Comment: [How to average time intervals?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/450581/458741) may also be of help - same issue, different aggregate function with a different solution that will also work.

Comment: I show examples of summing intervals in a previous SO post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661179/calculate-sum-of-spent-time/22662667#22662667) , hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks all. `select numtodsinterval(
             sum(
               extract (day from (timeDIff)) * 86400
                + extract (hour from (timeDIff)) * 3600
                 + extract (minute from (timeDIff)) * 60
                 + extract (second from (timeDIff))
        ), 'SECOND') as totalDiff`