# Calculate sum time in Oracle

Tags: oracle, time, sum, timestamp

I have this table in Oracle, email and time are varchar.

```
Email               Time
----------------    -----------
paolo@gmail.com     00:10:40
paolo@gmail.com     00:40:10
paolo@gmail.com     01:10:20
paolo@gmail.com     00:43:40
paolo@gmail.com     00:42:40
chiara@gmail.com    00:30:40
chiara@gmail.com    00:54:10
chiara@gmail.com    00:47:40
simo@gmail.com      00:50:40
simo@gmail.com      01:05:40
simo@gmail.com      00:45:40
simo@gmail.com      00:51:40
simo@gmail.com      00:36:40
```

I want to get sum of the time and group by email. Is it possibile in Oracle?

**UPDATES**

Time is duration.

Comment: I'm assuming thats duration not time, correct?

Comment: @tbone yes duration

Comment: Summing durations (in 11g anyway) is not straightforward, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812762/convert-varchar2-into-number/16816494#16816494)

Comment: I am afraid you might have to use PL/SQL for this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this query

```
SQL> WITH table_(Email, Time) as (
  2      select 'paolo@gmail.com', '00:10:40' from dual union all
  3      select 'paolo@gmail.com', '00:40:10' from dual union all
  4      select 'paolo@gmail.com', '01:10:20' from dual union all
  5      select 'paolo@gmail.com', '00:43:40' from dual union all
  6      select 'paolo@gmail.com', '00:42:40' from dual union all
  7      select 'chiara@gmail.com', '00:30:40' from dual union all
  8      select 'chiara@gmail.com', '00:54:10' from dual union all
  9      select 'chiara@gmail.com', '00:47:40' from dual union all
 10      select 'simo@gmail.com', '00:50:40' from dual union all
 11      select 'simo@gmail.com', '01:05:40' from dual union all
 12      select 'simo@gmail.com', '00:45:40' from dual union all
 13      select 'simo@gmail.com', '00:51:40' from dual union all
 14      select 'simo@gmail.com', '00:36:40' from dual )
 15  ---------------------
 16  -- End if sample data
 17  ---------------------
 18  SELECT email, numtodsinterval(sum(SUBSTR(TIME, 1, 2)*3600 + SUBSTR(TIME, 4, 2)*60 + SUBSTR(TIME, 7, 2)), 'SECOND') total_duration
 19    FROM table_
 20   GROUP BY email;
```

Output:

```
EMAIL            TOTAL_DURATION
---------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
chiara@gmail.com +000000000 02:12:30.000000000
simo@gmail.com   +000000000 04:10:20.000000000
paolo@gmail.com  +000000000 03:27:30.000000000
```

So, your query is

```
SELECT email, numtodsinterval(sum(SUBSTR(TIME, 1, 2)*3600 + SUBSTR(TIME, 4, 2)*60 + SUBSTR(TIME, 7, 2)), 'SECOND') total_duration
  FROM table_
 GROUP BY email;
```