# Add Sum() in query (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a working request:

```
SELECT Drivers.Surname, Drivers.Name, Waybills.StartTime,
       TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+(FinishTime - StartTime),'hh24:mi:ss') AS run_time
FROM Waybills JOIN
     Drivers
     ON Drivers.Id = Waybills.DriverId
WHERE Waybills.StartTime > SYSDATE-7 ORDER BY Name ASC;
```

But I can’t add sum in this place sum(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')+(FinishTime - StartTime),'hh24:mi:ss')) AS run_time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate sum time in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580381/calculate-sum-time-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do the sum on the difference, then add to a date and convert to a string:

```
TO_CHAR(date '1970-01-01' + sum(FinishTime - StartTime), 'hh24:mi:ss')
```

Based on your comment, your columns are `timestamp`s not `date`s.  You are only looking for second precision, so you might as well just convert to dates:

```
TO_CHAR(date '1970-01-01' + sum(cast(FinishTime as date) - cast(StartTime as dte)), 'hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: I get an error ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

Comment: @Allmood . . . That would suggest that your columns are *timestamps* and not *dates*.  For second precision, you might as well just convert to dates.

Comment: I get an error again(( ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: @Allmood . . . This addresses the question that you asked, which is how to add the sum of the differences in.  The query in your question obviously needs a `group by` because it is otherwise syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting `date` to `char` and adding difference of `timestamp` which is wrong.

You must do something like this:

```
DATE'1970-01-01' +(cast(FinishTime as date) - cast(StartTime as date)) AS run_time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try some workaround like this:

trunc( mod(mod(end_date - start_date,1)*24,1)*60 ) as mins ,
mod(mod(mod(end_date - start_date,1)*24,1)*60,1)*60 as secs

For the rest you can try these:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm#i1002084

After getting the result, you can easily wrap it to get a string format [with e.g. to_char(x, 'yyyy-mm-dd')]

Here are some more examples:

[Calculate difference between 2 date / times in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096853/calculate-difference-between-2-date-times-in-oracle-sql)